# different account types with different Links in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to make a simple site where users can  have different account levels.
For example, user with account type 'a' and 'b' will see a Link/button at the top which says basic and the users with account type 'c' will see a Link/button which says full member.

I have a code which will almost do what I need and it will save the users in different A/B/C categories in the database.

I just need to know what I have to do to be able to show different links to different account type as I explained above?

also, I know the code bellow is not the greatest codes but just need to achieve the results I am after for now with what I have.

```
<?php
session_start(); // Must start session first thing

// See if they are a logged in member by checking Session data
$toplinks = "";
if (isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // Put stored session variables into local php variable
    $userid = $_SESSION['id'];
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
    $toplinks = '<a href="member_profile.php?id=' . $userid . '">' . $username . '</a> &bull; 
    <a href="member_account.php">Account</a> &bull; 
    <a href="logout.php">Log Out</a>';
} else {
    echo 'Please <a href="login.php">log in</a> to access your account';
    exit(); 
}
?>
<?php
//Connect to the database through our include 
include_once "scripts/connect_to_mysql.php";
// Query member data from the database and ready it for display
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id='$userid'"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
$country = $row["country"];
$state = $row["state"];
$city = $row["city"];
$accounttype = $row["accounttype"]; 
$bio = $row["bio"]; 
}
// Give different options or display depending on which user type it is
if ($accounttype == "a") {
    $userOptions = "You get options for Expert User";
} else if ($accounttype == "b") {
    $userOptions = "You get options for Expert User";
} else if ($accounttype == "c") {
    $userOptions = "You get options for Expert User";
} else {
    $userOptions = "You get options for Super User";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Member Account</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    margin: 0px;
    background-image: url(imgs/bgnoise.png);
    background-repeat: repeat;
}
-->
</style>

</head>
<body>
<?php include_once("temps/template_header.php");?>
<table style="background-image: url(imgs/horizontal_nav_bg.jpg);"  repeat="x" width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="94" ><table style=" margin-left:20px; " width="734" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="156"><p><a href="edit_info.php" target="_self"><img src="imgs/info.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" "/>Edit Information</a></p></td>
        <td width="179"><a href="edit_pic.php" target="_self"><img src="imgs/very.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" />Verify Your Identity</a></td>
        <td width="126"><a href="member_profile.php?id=<?php echo "$userid"; ?>" target="_self"><img src="imgs/profile.png" width="35" height="35" border="0" />View Profile</a></td>


        <td width="138"><img src="imgs/basket.png" width="35" height="35" /><a href="http://somesite.com">Buy Bitcoin</a></td>
        <td width="135"><img src="imgs/user.png" width="35" height="35" alt="user" /><?php echo "$username"; ?></td>
        </tr>
      </table>      <h1>&nbsp;</h1></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<table width="700" align="right" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td><h3></h3></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<table width=950" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" style="line-height:1.5em;">
  <tr>
    <td width="118" valign="top" bgcolor="#E4E4E4"><h6>YOUR ACCOUNT<br />
        <a href="edit_info.php" target="_self">Edit Information </a><br />
        <a href="edit_pic.php" target="_self">Verify Your Identity</a><br />    
        <a href="member_profile.php?id=<?php echo "$userid"; ?>" target="_self">View Profile</a></h6>
      <h6><?php echo "$bio"; ?><br />
   </h6></td>
     <!-- See the more advanced member system tutorial to see how to place default placeholder pic until member uploads one -->
    <td width="160" valign="top"><div align="center"><img src="memberFiles/<?php echo "$userid"; ?>/pic1.jpg" alt="Ad" width="150" /></div></td>
    <td width="201" valign="top">
      Country: <?php echo "$country"; ?> <br />
      State: <?php echo "$state"; ?><br />
      City: <?php echo "$city"; ?>
      <table width="50" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
        </tr>
      </table>      <br />
    </td>
    <td width="430" margin="left" style="margin-right:0px;" rowspan="2" valign="top"><div id="veri"><img src="imgs/verifynote.png" width="430" height="600" /> </div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" valign="top"><br />
      <br />
    <br />
    <div style="overflow:hidden; width:100%px;">
  <iframe width="565" height="400"  scrolling="no" frameBorder="0"
  src="http://bitcoin.clarkmoody.com/widget/chart/" 
  style="width:728px; height:270px; border:none; margin-left:-60px;"/>  
</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<?php include_once("temps/template_footer.php");?>
</body>
</html>`
```

Please be gentle as I am a newbie in PHP and just learning the curves.

Thanks

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: I don't know what you're doing here. Have you considered using a [PHP framework](http://www.phpframeworks.com/top-10-php-frameworks/) to avoid creating an application consisting entirely of *code stew*?

Comment: ^^^^as true as it is, its getting a little tedious for regular S.O users to see it 10 times a day.

Comment: `mysql_query` is going to go away. If people aren't made aware of this, even to the point of getting browbeaten, then Stack Overflow will be inundated with "Why doesn't my app work?" questions when it's finally removed. There is no excuse to use `mysql_query` in a new application.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code

Comment: OH my days. good job I said be gentle as I am a newbie!! anyway, can I just replace the mysql_query comments with MySQLi ? I mean do I need to do anything further in order for it to work or just replacing them words would be enough ?

Comment: No, you should use prepared statements. Just adding a 'i' at the end wont help you.

Comment: so that makes spamming S.O ok then?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got this correctly but if you want according to the user's group to display different links just do:

```
if ($accounttype == "a") {
echo '<a href="">Page for user a</a>';
} 

else if ($accounttype == "b") {
    echo '<a href="">Page for user b</a>';

} else if ($accounttype == "c") {
    echo '<a href="">Page for user c</a>';
} else {
    echo '<a href="">Page for others</a>';
}
```

Also I suggest you to use mysqli. It is pretty similar to mysql. http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php (Myqsl is being removed)